# Variable importance for Random Forests time series in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, cross-validation

I use the randomForest package in R with a rolling window to predict returns on a financial time series (a stock).  I have developed a basket of features for this purpose and my goal is to understand their relative predictive power.

My challenge is I cannot use the variable importance feature of random forest because most of my features have a high degree of correlation with their recent past.  For example, a moving average spans a window of several days which means that it contains information across several observations in my data set.

This implies that the out-of-bag samples generated by random forest will be correlated with the in-sample features that random forests uses to train my model. Therefore the variable importance I would get from this would be highly optimistic and overfitted.

The solution I see is to somehow compute variable importance on an out-of-sample test set rather than using OOB cross-validation.  The goal is to ensure absolutely no correlation with the training set.

My question:  does a package exist in R to compute and extract variable importance from a test set rather than the standard OOB cross-validation set?  If not, can you suggest an approach to achieve this objective?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, great you thought of these correlations with the in-sample features.

Indeed, running your variable importance on a testset is a better idea. I think you can easily program this yourself. Here's some pseudo-code

```
check baseline performance metric
for variable in variables:
    random shuffle variable
    check performance metric
    save performance metric to disk
barplot(performance metrics)
```

Your performance metric can be anything: cross-entropy, accuracy, ROC-AUC and so on

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this.  Indeed, it looks like I may have to program it myself.  I was hoping to save myself that step.

The R package caret has a feature for RFE (Recursive Feature Elimination) that is interesting but it looks like you have to use cross-validation, which is a problem due to the correlation in time of the features.  Algorithm 2 mentioned below sounded like my solution (external resampling) but again, looks like I have to cross-validate.
http://topepo.github.io/caret/rfe.html 

Thanks for the insight!